# Numeric limit on composite key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, composite

My `RelationshipCodeLookup` table uses as a foreign key the primary key field of the `AgentTransmission` table. There can be only 5 records in the `RelationshipCodeLookup` table with the same `AgentTransmission` primary key.

Is it possible to create a composite key on the `RelationshipCodeLookup` which includes the foreign key from `AgentTransmission` and a separate `int` field that only goes up to 5? For instance, a complete group of records for one agent would be:

```
FK   CK
132   1
132   2
132   3
132   4
132   5
```

If another record was attempted to be added with the `FK` of `132`, some kind of constraint on the table would be violated and the record unable to be added.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think a simple check constraint on the CK column would do what you need.  The Check constraint requires that values in the CK column are in the specified range ( 1 thru 5 ).

```
CREATE TABLE RelationshipCodeLookup(
    FK INT NOT NULL, 
    CK INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_RelationshipCodeLookup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( FK, CK )  
);
ALTER TABLE RelationshipCodeLookup WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RelationshipCodeLookup CHECK (CK>=1 AND CK<=5);
ALTER TABLE RelationshipCodeLookup CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_RelationshipCodeLookup;
```